# How to overwrite ctrl + a select all from list box?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was hoping that this code below would overwrite it, since I am assigning new stuff. But instead it executes both, selecting all and my message box

```
private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ctrl a");
    }
}
```

please help thanks

Comment: Does `e.Handled = true` prevent the select all?

Comment: it doesn't prevent, same issue adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle the [PreviewKeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for the `ListBox`, you should be able to mark the event as handled, and the `Ctrl+A` should be ignored:

```
private void OnListBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```